# Comparing two three-digits number

Tags: python, digits

I got stuck in a game called 'strike or ball'

IndexError came out.

This has a very simple rule.
If I put three digits whose type is 'str', it is being compared with another three digits made by 'random'.

1. If they share only one digit and it's placed in same space. e.g 274, 286
   it goes to only one 'strike'
2. Even though sharing one digit and in different space, e.g 274, 826
   it goes to only one 'ball'
3. if, in the end, I put in three digits correctly, it goes to '3 strikes'.

("123", "472") [0, 1]

("742", "472") [1, 2]

("472", "472") [3, 0]

This is some examples.

Here is my try, which is, of course, wrong...

```
def get_strikes_or_ball(user_input_number, random_number):
    a = str(user_input_number)
    b = str(random_number)
    c = [val for val in a if val in b]
    i = 0
    strike = 0
    ball = 0
    while c:
        if a[i] == b[i]:
            strikes = strikes + 1
        elif a[i] == b[i+1]:
            ball = ball + 1
        elif a[i] == b[e+2]:
            ball = ball + 1
    result = str('strike : ', strike,"  ", 'ball : ', ball)
    # ==================================
    return result
```

Comment: Explain what is wrong with your code - is there an error? Unexpected output? And ask a question.

Comment: a guess - are you entering an infinite loop? it might happen - you define a list `c`, which evaluates to `True` as long as it's not empty, and you never modify it

Comment: IndexError came out. I don't know how to track digits in 'a' while every single list value in 'b' (e.g b[0],b[1],...) moves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to count how many numbers in a are also in b in the same position (strikes) or in another position (balls). If this is correct the this should do it:

```
for i in range(0, 3):
    if a[i] in b:
        if a[i] == b[i]:
            strikes = strikes + 1
        else:
            balls = balls + 1
```

Comment: You don't need that `if a[i] in b:` line; `if a[i] == b[i]` covers it.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I can move it in the else case but not remove it or you'd be adding balls even if `a[i]` is not in `b` which is wrong. In the case `a[i] not in b` nothing should be done

Comment: Oops, you're right. I missed the `else` somehow. Carry on!